# With B”H more people living to over 70, are there implications for the mitzvah of מפני שיבה תקום והדרת פני זקן

Tags: age, standing-sitting, kavod

There is a [mitzvah](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Standing_for_Talmidei_Chachamim_and_the_Elderly#cite_note-1)  to get up for a person aged over 70.

The link on the word “mitzvah” goes to Halchipedia. The first footnote relates to the age 70 and reads:

> S”A YD 244:1 writes that it is a positive command to stand up for an
>   elderly person of age 70. This is from the pasuk in the Torah (Vayikra
>   19:32) מפני שיבה תקום והדרת פני זקן. Kitzur S”A 144:2, Chaye Adam
>   69:2, and Aruch HaShulchan 244:1 agree. Birkei Yosef 244:4, however,
>   quotes the Arizal who says that one should stand for a person of age
>   60. Sh”t Yabia Omer 3:13 and 9:13 writes that while the halacha follows S”A, one who is strict for the Arizal will be blessed.

We are grateful to Hashem that a larger proportion of the population is now over 70 years old than was the case over many years.

Has anyone commented on the nature of this mitzvah in these changed circumstances?

[This excellent shiur by Rabbi Herschel Schachter](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/890668/rabbi-hershel-schachter/nishtanu-hatvaim/) explains that there are halochos where change in circumstances allow a change in the din (and halochos where they do not).

Comment: Can you edit an explanation as to how the word שיבה calculates to age 70? I think Pirkei Avot alludes to that, but it's not obvious in your question.

Comment: Would the underlying rationale be since there’s a large proportion of 70 year olds therefore such a senior doesn’t carry distinction to-day, or since there’s such a large proportion its “burdensome” to keep the implications of said *mitzvah*?

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting here.

Comment: Why would it change? You're assuming the mitzvah is because they achieved some accomplishment? Because it's rare? I've heard it's respect because of their collected life experience

Comment: @robev please read my answer.

Comment: @DanF I have added something justifying 70 - halocho and not parshonus.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am looking for a source which will read something like "From these ma'amorei chazal, it is clear that setting the age of 70 to rise before an older person is contingent on the average lifespan being considerably less. Now since worldwide, the **average life expectancy** at birth was 67 years for males for 2016 according to to The World Factbook, it is clear to me that the minimum age at which one must rise for an older person is x years."

Comment: Someone over 70 does not have to stand up for another person over 70. So you can tell the age of a person in a place where halacha is kept

Comment: Can @patient provide a source for that please? I thought that one 70-year old has to slightly raise himself for another one. But more important - are you just providing information or what please is your point in posting this?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok How would the average life span make a difference?

Comment: Thanks. The halacha is good info. I was hoping, though, that they would provide a source for how they derived those ages.

Answer (score -2):

Well, Oliver's comment caused me to publish this as an answer:

Actually for Mitzvos בין אדם לחבירו we do take into consideration cultural and social circumstances. As we experience huge changes in those areas we observe how those Mitzvahs' observance changes with time. Examples:

- **Tzedakka:** Halachicly you're obligated to provide full support for EVERY needy that turns to you, but once there are so many (in Meah Shearim for instance) you pick who you help to and how much. You are not obligated to do "the full Mitzvah" for every needy".
- **Honoring Parents:** Halachically one is obligated to stand before his parents and so it was for centuries. Norms changed, and you won't find that today in most frum families.
- **Returning lost property:** Norms have changed dramatically with the technological advances. If you come by a building (Jewish) with its lights on you don't scream "השבת אבידה", it is very acceptable nowadays. The bar for returning property has raised significantly, nobody returns pens, Kipas or other small items.
- **Standing before Rabbis in a Kolel:** Halachically one is obligated to stand before every Rabbi, but once there are too many it interferes with learning Torah or other activities, one becomes automatically Potur.

Note: A possible Halachic Ptur for the mentioned behaviors is that it is ruled that as the person himself precedes other in all Mitzvos בין אדם לחבירו, like אבידתך קודמת, those Mitzvos should not come at expense of personal suffering. Once a person suffers, he precedes others, and that takes over the Mitzvah.

Same here, once there are too many elders, a person can pick when and to whom he'd like to perform that Mitzvah and technically Potur from others.

Same here, once there are so many elders, you pick when to do the Mitzvah.

Comment: Haven't ve agreed not to downvote without commenting?

Comment: I feel really bad for you, Al. It seems a lot of your answers on here get downvoted. I think it might be because you don't present any sources.